# Going from arduino & sketch to production

Tags: arduino-uno

I've got a little proof of concept thing going here with an arduino & Ethernet shield. The basic idea is for it to ping out much like a heartbeat monitor every so often so I can see if my house still has internet connectivity.

The arduino works nicely and does exactly what I want. I've ordered a board to be made with just the basic components needed and now want to put the code on to it. They gave me an option to load the code (Dragon AVR) during checkout and I'd love to try that out. So, the question is - how on earth do I package up code for something like that? I've seen a number of people ask the same thing for large manufacturing scales / similar setup where they don't fancy using the arduino & IDE as a programmer.

I've asked around on IRC and various other places but nobody seems to be able to give me specific and clear advice on whether it's possible and how to go about doing it.

Comment: Don't forget to also provide the fuse settings. Fuses on the Arduino are different from those that are set when the chips leave the factory.

Comment: @Gerben how would I be able to define that?

Comment: Not sure. It's just 3 bytes, so you can just send them the three values I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Intel Hex" is pretty much an industry standard and I'm quite certain the .hex files produced by the GNU AVR tools is Intel Hex format. Your vendor is almost certainly prepared to load your sketch from the .hex file.

Comment: Have to agree. But it can't hurt to ask if they can support the ELF file as well.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you for not replying with "easy" and that's it! If you don't mind me asking, the hex file that is produced when I load my sketch onto the arduino should be "build ready"? I.e just ship them that?

Comment: Or how do I generate the ELF? Sorry guys!

Comment: Both files are products of the compile/load process. If you're using the Arduino IDE, I can't help you much with the locations of those files (though I'm sure someone here knows, for whichever OS you use). I know the Eclipse IDE puts those files in a folder named for the board or configuration, within each particular project.

Comment: Whenever I program my chips using ICSP I always use the exact same .hex file that is output by the IDE. I hope you have an ICSP header on your board in case you ever need to change the code.

Comment: That sounds promising. Literally just lift the hex file and away we go? Is it that simple?

Comment: Check with your vendor to be sure, but probably, yes.